# ffmpeg.exe : Missing MFPlat.dll in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am using ffmpeg to convert .m3u8 playlist to single mp4 file.
I download the Windows EXE Files from http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows successfully.
But when I open the ffmpeg.exe, an error message appears that says MFPlat.dll is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending a lot of time I found that MFPlat.DLL is the dll of Windows Media Player. Windows Media Player is not installed by default in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.
To overcome this problem we have to install it. To install follow these steps below:

Go to Server Manager.

1. Click Features → Add Features.
2. Check "Desktop Experience".
3. Click "Install".
4. After all, restart the computer.

Following these steps resolved my problem.